# R how to fill in a missing Date based on context

Tags: r, date, time-series, missing-data

I have a survival database that I have created that describes survival for experimental units (`Module #`).  What I am looking to do is fill in any missing dates in Date.y with the date entry for the other module side for a particular TimeStep because both module sides were always sampled on the same day.  For example for TimeStep_start == 4, `Module #` 115 does not have a date entry for the south (S) side (refer to row 14 in the provided database).  However, the north (N) side (row 13) does have a date entry for that TimeStep_start == 4.  I want to write some code that would automatically fill in the missing date info with the date from the other side of that same module.  I have attached a database here to be used for reference to give context as well as the function I wrote to create this database.  If possible, I would think it better to alter the function to fill in dates so that way it is applied the same to all input databases regardless of their structure.  Thanks in advance!

#### DATABASE WRITING FUNCTION

```
Survival_calc <- function(data, data_1, TimeStep_1, TimeStep_2, quarter){
  data <- sub_3
  data_1 <- data_final
  Exclusion <- c("NF","D", "ND")
  Grouping <- c("Date", "Site_long", "Shelter", "Module #", "Side")

  Col_name <- paste(quarter, "Survival", sep = "_")

  Start <- data %>% filter(TimeStep == TimeStep_1, !`Status Code` %in% Exclusion)

  End <- data_1 %>% filter(TimeStep == TimeStep_2) %>%
    inner_join(Start, by = c("ID", "Side", "Site_long", "Shelter", "Module #")) %>%
    rename(Date = Date.x,
           Status_Code = `Status Code.x`)


  Start_summary <- Start %>% group_by_at(Grouping) %>% 
    count()

  End_summary <- End %>% group_by_at(Grouping) %>% 
    summarize(corals = n(),
              dead = sum(Status_Code %in% Exclusion),
              n = corals - dead)


  result_long <-  left_join(Start_summary, End_summary, by = c("Site_long", "Shelter", "Module #", "Side")) %>% 
    mutate(survived = replace_na(n.y, 0)) %>% 
    mutate(TimeStep_start = TimeStep_1) %>% 
    mutate(TimeStep_end = TimeStep_2) %>% 
    mutate("Survival_prop" = (survived/n.x)) %>% 
    mutate(Quarter = quarter)


  result_wide <-  left_join(Start_summary, End_summary, by = Grouping) %>% 
    replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
    transmute(!!Col_name := (n.y/n.x) * 100)

  return(result_long)

}
```

#### HEAD OF DATA

```
# A tibble: 20 x 15
# Groups:   Date.x, Site_long, Shelter, Module #, Side [51]
   Date.x     Site_long   Shelter `Module #` Side  Date.y       n.x corals  dead   n.y survived TimeStep_start TimeStep_end Survival_prop Quarter
   <date>     <fct>       <fct>        <dbl> <chr> <date>     <int>  <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2017-05-02 Hanauma Bay High           213 N     2017-08-08     2      2     1     1        1              1            4           0.5       1
 2 2017-05-02 Hanauma Bay High           215 S     2017-08-08     1      1     0     1        1              1            4           1         1
 3 2017-05-06 Waikiki     Low            116 S     2017-08-09     3      3     0     3        3              1            4           1         1
 4 2017-05-13 Waikiki     High           115 N     2017-08-09     1      1     0     1        1              1            4           1         1
 5 2017-05-13 Waikiki     High           115 S     2017-08-11     1      1     1     0        0              1            4           0         1
 6 2017-05-13 Waikiki     Low            114 N     2017-08-11     5      5     1     4        4              1            4           0.8       1
 7 2017-05-13 Waikiki     Low            114 S     2017-08-11     5      5     1     4        4              1            4           0.8       1
 8 2017-05-20 Waikiki     Low            112 N     2017-08-11     1      1     1     0        0              1            4           0         1
 9 2017-05-20 Waikiki     Low            112 S     2017-08-11     1      1     0     1        1              1            4           1         1
10 2017-05-24 Waikiki     High           111 S     2017-08-09     1      1     0     1        1              1            4           1         1
11 2017-08-08 Hanauma Bay High           213 N     2017-11-14     1      1     0     1        1              4            5           1         2
12 2017-08-08 Hanauma Bay High           215 N     2017-11-14     3      3     0     3        3              4            5           1         2
13 2017-08-09 Waikiki     High           115 N     2017-11-05     1      1     0     1        1              4            5           1         2
14 2017-08-11 Waikiki     High           115 S     NA             1     NA    NA    NA        0              4            5           0         2
15 2017-08-11 Waikiki     Low            112 N     2017-11-05     1      1     0     1        1              4            5           1         2
16 2017-08-11 Waikiki     Low            112 S     2017-11-05     2      1     0     1        1              4            5           0.5       2
17 2017-08-11 Waikiki     Low            114 N     2017-11-12     1      1     0     1        1              4            5           1         2
18 2017-08-12 Waikiki     High           113 N     2017-11-10     1      1     0     1        1              4            5           1         2
19 2017-08-26 Waikiki     Low            114 S     NA             1     NA    NA    NA        0              4            5           0         2
20 2017-11-05 Waikiki     Low            112 S     2018-03-13     1      1     0     1        1              5            6           1         3
```

#### DATABASE

```
data <- structure(list(Date.x = structure(c(17288, 17288, 17292, 17299, 
17299, 17299, 17299, 17306, 17306, 17310, 17386, 17386, 17387, 
17389, 17389, 17389, 17389, 17390, 17404, 17475, 17480, 17480, 
17484, 17575, 17575, 17575, 17575, 17575, 17575, 17582, 17586, 
17586, 17594, 17600, 17601, 17601, 17601, 17603, 17603, 17603, 
17675, 17675, 17675, 17675, 17677, 17677, 17680, 17680, 17680, 
17682, 17684, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17773, 
17773, 17773, 17773, 17780, 17780, 17780, 17780, 17782, 17782, 
17782, 17782, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 
17783, 17783, 17783, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17860, 17860, 
17860, 17860, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 
17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17869, 17869, 17953, 17953, 17953, 
17953, 17953, 17957, 17957, 17957, 17957, 17960, 17960, 17960, 
17960, 17964, 17964, 17964, 17964, 17965, 17965, 17965, 17965, 
17967, 17967, 17971, 18037, 18037, 18037, 18039, 18039, 18039, 
18039, 18044, 18044, 18044, 18044, 18044, 18046, 18046, 18046, 
18046, 18047, 18047, 18048, 18048, 18054, 18058, 18135, 18135, 
18135, 18135, 18135, 18139, 18139, 18139, 18139, 18140, 18140, 
18140, 18142, 18142, 18142, 18144, 18144, 18144, 18149), class = "Date"), 
    Site_long = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"
    ), class = "factor"), Shelter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("High", 
    "Low"), class = "factor"), `Module #` = c(213, 215, 116, 
    115, 115, 114, 114, 112, 112, 111, 213, 215, 115, 115, 112, 
    112, 114, 113, 114, 112, 113, 113, 215, 213, 213, 215, 214, 
    216, 216, 211, 116, 116, 115, 113, 113, 114, 114, 111, 112, 
    112, 113, 113, 116, 116, 115, 115, 215, 215, 216, 112, 111, 
    213, 212, 212, 214, 214, 216, 115, 115, 112, 112, 111, 111, 
    114, 114, 113, 113, 116, 116, 211, 211, 213, 213, 215, 215, 
    212, 212, 216, 216, 113, 113, 114, 114, 111, 111, 116, 116, 
    211, 211, 215, 215, 212, 214, 216, 115, 115, 112, 112, 213, 
    213, 211, 212, 212, 216, 216, 115, 115, 112, 112, 213, 213, 
    214, 214, 111, 111, 116, 116, 113, 113, 114, 114, 215, 215, 
    211, 215, 215, 212, 113, 113, 114, 114, 213, 213, 214, 216, 
    216, 111, 111, 116, 116, 112, 112, 115, 115, 114, 212, 211, 
    212, 214, 214, 216, 113, 113, 114, 114, 115, 115, 112, 213, 
    215, 215, 111, 111, 116, 213), Side = c("N", "S", "S", "N", 
    "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", 
    "N", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "S", "S", "S", "N", 
    "S", "N", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", 
    "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", 
    "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", 
    "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", 
    "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", 
    "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", 
    "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", 
    "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", 
    "N", "S", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "S", 
    "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", "S", 
    "N", "S", "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", 
    "S", "N", "S", "N", "S"), Date.y = structure(c(17386, 17386, 
    17387, 17387, 17389, 17389, 17389, 17389, 17389, 17387, 17484, 
    17484, 17475, NA, 17475, 17475, 17482, 17480, NA, 17603, 
    17600, 17600, 17575, 17687, 17687, 17680, 17687, 17680, 17687, 
    17687, NA, 17675, 17677, 17675, 17675, 17682, 17682, 17684, 
    17682, 17682, 17782, 17782, 17782, 17782, NA, 17773, 17783, 
    17783, 17783, 17773, 17780, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 
    17783, 17867, 17867, NA, 17867, 17860, 17860, 17859, 17859, 
    17859, 17859, 17860, 17860, NA, 17862, 17869, 17869, 17862, 
    17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17965, 17965, 17965, 17965, 
    17964, 17964, 17964, 17964, 17953, 17971, 17967, 17967, 17953, 
    17960, 17953, 17957, 17957, 17957, 17957, 17960, 17960, 18037, 
    18037, 18037, 18044, 18044, 18048, 18048, 18047, 18047, 18044, 
    18044, 18044, 18044, 18046, 18046, 18046, 18046, 18039, 18039, 
    18039, 18039, 18037, 18037, 18037, 18142, 18142, 18135, 18139, 
    18139, 18139, 18139, 18142, 18142, 18135, 18135, 18135, 18144, 
    18144, 18144, 18144, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18139, 18135, 
    18226, 18226, 18226, 18226, 18226, 18223, 18223, 18224, 18224, 
    18230, 18230, 18230, 18233, 18233, 18233, 18231, 18231, 18231, 
    18233), class = "Date"), n.x = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
    16L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
    2L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
    2L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 10L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 12L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 
    5L, 26L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 
    16L, 13L, 6L, 1L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    5L, 7L, 1L), corals = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, NA, 8L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 14L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 8L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 
    4L, NA, 1L, 9L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    12L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 25L, 9L, 6L, 
    5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 14L, 12L, 6L, 1L, 
    10L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
    3L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L), dead = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, NA, 0L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 12L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
    0L), n.y = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, NA, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
    12L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
    9L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), survived = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 
    4, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 5, 
    2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 1, 1, 4, 2, 
    3, 0, 7, 7, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 6, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 6, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 4, 
    1, 9, 4, 5, 2, 12, 2, 1, 10, 10, 0, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 0, 3, 
    2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 6, 10, 3, 13, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 
    9, 2, 13, 10, 5, 0, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 
    2, 2, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 0, 
    2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1), TimeStep_start = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14
    ), TimeStep_end = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
    15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15), Survival_prop = c(0.5, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.833333333333333, 0.4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.625, 
    0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.8, 1, 1, 0, 0.777777777777778, 
    1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.1875, 0.25, 1, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 
    0.75, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.571428571428571, 0.4, 
    0.6, 0, 1, 0.111111111111111, 1, 0.545454545454545, 1, 0, 
    0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0, 1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.5, 
    1, 0.923076923076923, 1, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 
    0, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0, 1, 0.5, 
    0.333333333333333, 0, 0.75, 0.363636363636364, 0.857142857142857, 
    0.909090909090909, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.714285714285714, 0.2, 
    0.4, 0.25, 0.833333333333333, 1, 0.875, 0.428571428571429, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.818181818181818, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.8125, 0.769230769230769, 0.833333333333333, 0, 0.416666666666667, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.75, 0.571428571428571, 0.375, 0.714285714285714, 
    0.6, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.285714285714286, 
    0, 0.454545454545455, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 
    0.75, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 0.75, 0.333333333333333, 
    1, 0.666666666666667, 0.4, 0.428571428571429, 1), Quarter = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-165L), groups = structure(list(Date.x = structure(c(17288, 17288, 
17288, 17288, 17288, 17292, 17292, 17292, 17292, 17299, 17299, 
17299, 17299, 17299, 17299, 17306, 17306, 17306, 17306, 17306, 
17310, 17310, 17310, 17310, 17386, 17386, 17386, 17386, 17386, 
17387, 17387, 17387, 17387, 17389, 17389, 17389, 17389, 17389, 
17389, 17390, 17390, 17390, 17390, 17404, 17404, 17404, 17404, 
17475, 17475, 17475, 17475, 17480, 17480, 17480, 17480, 17480, 
17484, 17484, 17484, 17484, 17575, 17575, 17575, 17575, 17575, 
17575, 17575, 17575, 17582, 17582, 17582, 17582, 17586, 17586, 
17586, 17586, 17586, 17594, 17594, 17594, 17594, 17600, 17600, 
17600, 17600, 17601, 17601, 17601, 17601, 17601, 17603, 17603, 
17603, 17603, 17603, 17675, 17675, 17675, 17675, 17675, 17675, 
17677, 17677, 17677, 17677, 17677, 17680, 17680, 17680, 17680, 
17680, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17684, 17684, 17684, 17684, 
17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17687, 17773, 
17773, 17773, 17773, 17773, 17773, 17780, 17780, 17780, 17780, 
17780, 17780, 17782, 17782, 17782, 17782, 17782, 17782, 17783, 
17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 17783, 
17783, 17783, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17859, 17860, 
17860, 17860, 17860, 17860, 17860, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 
17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17862, 17867, 17867, 17867, 17867, 
17867, 17867, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17953, 17953, 
17953, 17953, 17953, 17953, 17953, 17957, 17957, 17957, 17957, 
17957, 17957, 17960, 17960, 17960, 17960, 17960, 17960, 17964, 
17964, 17964, 17964, 17964, 17964, 17965, 17965, 17965, 17965, 
17965, 17965, 17967, 17967, 17967, 17967, 17967, 17971, 17971, 
17971, 17971, 18037, 18037, 18037, 18037, 18037, 18039, 18039, 
18039, 18039, 18039, 18039, 18044, 18044, 18044, 18044, 18044, 
18044, 18044, 18046, 18046, 18046, 18046, 18046, 18046, 18047, 
18047, 18047, 18047, 18047, 18048, 18048, 18048, 18048, 18048, 
18054, 18054, 18054, 18054, 18058, 18058, 18058, 18058, 18135, 
18135, 18135, 18135, 18135, 18135, 18135, 18139, 18139, 18139, 
18139, 18139, 18139, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18142, 
18142, 18142, 18142, 18142, 18142, 18144, 18144, 18144, 18144, 
18144, 18149, 18149, 18149, 18149), class = "Date"), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", 
"Waikiki"), class = "factor"), Shelter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
"Low"), class = "factor"), `Module #` = c(213, 215, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 116, NA, NA, 115, 115, 114, 114, NA, NA, NA, 112, 
112, NA, NA, 111, NA, 213, 215, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 115, NA, 
NA, NA, 115, 112, 112, 114, NA, NA, 113, NA, NA, NA, NA, 114, 
NA, NA, NA, 112, NA, NA, 113, 113, NA, 215, NA, NA, NA, 213, 
213, 215, 214, 216, 216, NA, NA, 211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
116, 116, NA, NA, 115, NA, NA, NA, 113, NA, NA, NA, 113, 114, 
114, NA, NA, 111, 112, 112, NA, NA, 113, 113, 116, 116, NA, NA, 
115, 115, NA, 215, 215, 216, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 112, NA, NA, 
111, NA, 213, 212, 212, 214, 214, 216, NA, NA, NA, NA, 115, 115, 
112, 112, NA, NA, 111, 111, 114, 114, NA, NA, 113, 113, 116, 
116, 211, 211, 213, 213, 215, 215, 212, 212, 216, 216, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 113, 113, 114, 114, NA, NA, 111, 111, 116, 116, 211, 
211, 215, 215, 212, 214, 216, NA, NA, NA, NA, 115, 115, 112, 
112, 213, 213, NA, NA, NA, 211, 212, 212, 216, 216, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 115, 115, 112, 112, 213, 213, 214, 214, NA, NA, NA, NA, 111, 
111, 116, 116, NA, NA, 113, 113, 114, 114, 215, 215, NA, NA, 
NA, 211, NA, NA, NA, 215, 215, 212, NA, NA, NA, NA, 113, 113, 
114, 114, 213, 213, 214, 216, 216, NA, NA, NA, NA, 111, 111, 
116, 116, NA, NA, NA, 112, 112, NA, NA, 115, 115, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 114, NA, 212, NA, NA, 211, 212, 214, 214, 216, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 113, 113, 114, 114, NA, NA, 115, 115, 112, 213, 215, 215, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 111, 111, 116, 213, NA, NA, NA), Side = c("N", 
"S", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", 
NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", NA, NA, "S", NA, "N", "N", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "N", NA, NA, NA, "S", "N", "S", "N", NA, NA, "N", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "S", NA, NA, NA, "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", NA, "N", 
NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", "S", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", NA, NA, "S", NA, NA, NA, "N", NA, NA, 
NA, "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", 
"S", NA, NA, "N", "S", NA, "N", "S", "N", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"S", NA, NA, "S", NA, "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", "S", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", 
"S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", 
"N", "S", "N", "S", "S", "N", "N", NA, NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", 
"N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, NA, "N", "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "S", 
NA, NA, NA, "S", NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", "S", NA, NA, NA, NA, "N", 
"S", "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", "N", "S", NA, NA, NA, NA, "N", 
"S", "N", "S", NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "N", NA, "N", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", "N", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "N", "N", 
"S", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, NA, NA), .rows = list(
    1L, 2L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), 3L, integer(0), integer(0), 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), 8L, 9L, integer(0), integer(0), 10L, 
    integer(0), 11L, 12L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), 13L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, integer(0), integer(0), 18L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 19L, integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), 20L, integer(0), integer(0), 21L, 22L, integer(0), 
    23L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, integer(0), integer(0), 30L, integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 31L, 32L, 
    integer(0), integer(0), 33L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    34L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 35L, 36L, 37L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), 38L, 39L, 40L, integer(0), integer(0), 41L, 42L, 
    43L, 44L, integer(0), integer(0), 45L, 46L, integer(0), 47L, 
    48L, 49L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), 50L, integer(0), integer(0), 51L, integer(0), 
    52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, integer(0), integer(0), 62L, 
    63L, 64L, 65L, integer(0), integer(0), 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
    70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
    93L, 94L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 114L, 115L, 
    116L, 117L, integer(0), integer(0), 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
    122L, 123L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 124L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), 125L, 126L, 127L, integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
    134L, 135L, 136L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    141L, 142L, integer(0), integer(0), 143L, 144L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 145L, integer(0), 146L, 
    integer(0), integer(0), 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 
    integer(0), integer(0), 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), row.names = c(NA, 
-304L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy might be to `fill` in the missing `Date.y` after grouping by both `TimeStep_start` and `Module #`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(TimeStep_start, `Module #`) %>%
  fill(Date.y, .direction = "updown")
```

Comment: I tried to use your code provided and received the following error message: Error in match.arg(.direction) : 'arg' should be one of “down”, “up”.  The issue with this is indicating either "up" or "down" will not be useful as sometimes the date to pull will be above the blank entry and other times it may be below it.

Comment: What version of `tidyverse` or `tidyr` are you using? The latest `tidyr` uses `up`, `down`, `updown` or `downup`. See: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html

Comment: I have Tidyverse v 1.2.1 installed.  I will install 1.3 and see if that changes anything